# Python Web Scraping Airlines Data, Idea of Implementation

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is an open and general question. I would need opinions and advice, concerning the feasibilty of an operation I wish do in Python.

I was wondering how it would be possible by using Python to go through websites of several airlines, no comparators like Kayak or tripadvisor, only their own website ex: https://www.skyairline.com/chile and get the price of a ticket for a given period and given destination from a main city. The idea is really simple and it seems that a loop would do the job. This is a very long and boring manual process, that is why I want to create this program.

See below the idea of output:

```
Departure from "Main city"  to City A, City B ... City D

From- To:   01/03/18-02/05/18      08/04/18-08/15/18       09/04/18-09/15/18      
   City A         XXX$                   XXX$                    XXX$  
   City B         XXX$                   XXX$                    XXX$  
   City C         XXX$                   XXX$                    XXX$   
   City D         XXX$                   XXX$                    XXX$
```

However, I have never done such a thing and don't have experience in web scraping.

First of all, what do you think of the feasibility of such thing for a beginner? 
Should I use beautifulsoup? 
I have good notions in data analysis in R, but none in Python, and I really want learn more about this language.

Thank you for some clarification about how should I get started with it.

Comment: Consider using [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) and/or [portia](https://scrapinghub.com/portia).

Comment: Ok, scrapy would be more adapted than beautiful soup then.

Comment: The scrapy spider would be able to crawl the site and store pricing data. Portia allows you to build the spider visually if you're new to building spiders.

Comment: Very useful thanks. Therefore once I did it for one airline 's website, do you think it would take the same amount of time to do so for others airlines'website as each website has its own specificities (programming language, data base structure...)  You think Builldig the spider will be the hardest?

Comment: Each website will have its own DOM schema you need to learn. You should start with a basic [intro](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html#walk-through-of-an-example-spider)